# Jaccard in Keras

Tags: keras

I am trying to use jaccard as metrics in my Keras LSTM.

The Jaccard has been defined as follow:

```python
def jaccard_similarity(doc1, doc2):
    print (doc1.eval())
    intersection = set(doc1).intersection(set(doc2))
    union = set(doc1).union(set(doc2))
    return len(intersection)/len(union)
```

This does not work because doc1 and 2 are tensors. I first need to convert them into lists. I tried to apply .eval() to the input tensors I want to calculate the Jaccard on but I get an error

ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered.

Maybe I better off  applying  (but I am not sure they exits) the tensors version for the union, set and intersection functions.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following :

```
intersection = K.sum(K.abs(doc1 * doc2), axis=-1)
sum_ = K.sum(K.abs(doc1) + K.abs(doc2), axis=-1)
jac = (intersection + smooth) / (sum_ - intersection + smooth)
return (1 - jac) * smooth
```